# replace DOM node with Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have an ajax response which looks like this:

```
<div class = "element3"> some other text</div>
```

and I want to replace element1 in the following with resp:

```
<div class = "a">
  <div class = "element1"></div>
  <div class = "element2"></div>
</div>
```

So after the replace I would get:

```
<div class = "a">
  <div class = "element3"> some other text</div>
  <div class = "element2"></div>
</div>
```

I tried replaceChild() but it does not work because the response is not a DOM object..

Thanks!

Comment: If using jquery, use `replaceWith`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `innerHTML()` which only replaces the content between the tags, `outerHTML()` will allow you to replace the opening & closing tags as well, effectively replacing the DOM node.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('element1')[0];
element.outerHTML("<div class = 'element3'> some other text</div>");
```

See:

- http://help.dottoro.com/ljloliex.php
- http://help.dottoro.com/ljdkwhqf.php

Note: Due to the use of `getElementsByClassName()`, this solution is valid for (see: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname):

- Internet Explorer 9+
- Firefox 3+
- Opera 9.5+
- Chrome 4+
- Safari 3.1+

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the text, set the `innerText` property on the target element. If you want to insert all the HTML, set the `innerHTML` property on the target element. To replace the target element itself, I believe you can use `outerHTML`.

Comment: basically i want to delete element1 and add element3, innerHTML on "a" will also get rid of element2, and innerHTML on element1 will result in <div class = "element1"><div class = "element3"> some other text</div></div> @Trott

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, while you already have an answer, the following:

```
var newContent = '<div class = "element3"> some other text</div>',
    temp = document.createElement('div'),
    div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('element1')[0];

temp.innerHTML = newContent;

div1.parentNode.replaceChild(temp.firstChild, div1);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DuZz7/).

Given that your problem was, basically, that the 'new content' wasn't a DOM node the most sensible solution is to simply *make* it a DOM node. Though this does, of course, carry the cross-browser caveats of using `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

And below is a cross-browser version that *should* provide a fall-back for those browsers that don't support `document.getElementsByClassName()` (works with IE 7, other versions not available; it's worth noting that the ternary condition may require an upgrade to cope with how some of those browsers might handle the conditional assessment):

```
function findByClassName(classname, el) {
    if (!classname) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el = !el ? document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] : el;
        var children = el.getElementsByTagName('*'),
            withClass = [];

        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
                var classes = children[i].className.split(/\s+/);
                for (var c = 0, leng = classes.length; c < leng; c++) {
                    if (classes[c] == classname) {
                        withClass.push(children[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return withClass;
    }
}

var newContent = '<div class = "element3"> some other text</div>',
    temp = document.createElement('div'),
    div1 = document.getElementsByClassName ? document.getElementsByClassName('element1')[0] : findByClassName('element1')[0];

temp.innerHTML = newContent;

div1.parentNode.replaceChild(temp.firstChild, div1);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DuZz7/1/).

References:

- [Compatibility for `document.getElementsByClassName()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).
- [Compatibility for `element.outerHTML`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4xVd/) example to replace a DOMElement with another.

```
<div class = "a">
<div class="element1">--</div>
  <div class="element2">--</div>
</div>

<div class="element3"> some other text</div>

var element = document.getElementsByClassName('element1')[0];
var replacement = document.getElementsByClassName('element3')[0];
element.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, element);
```